# How to setup tikz/pgfplots to not put ticks labels outside the axis area?

Tags: ticks

I have the following figure:

[image]

I want to remove the -5 tick label or any tick label that is outside of the axis area by default using `\pgfplotsset`. Is there any way to do that.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Actually all tick's labels are outside of axis :-). I guess that you looking for something like this `xtick = {-40,-35,...,-10}`.

Comment: Something like that but i would like to find a way to make this change systematic. I mean i use matlab2tikz (https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22022-matlab2tikz-matlab2tikz ) script to export figures from matlab to Tikz. I would like to change this script to each time that i create one figure and export it to pgfplots it sets the header of the tex file ( \documentclass[tikz]{standalone} and so on) inside the \pgfplotsset to make this change by default. Therefore i can guarantee that all generated pgfplots figures have the same size, on scientific papers.

Comment: you can put `xtick={...}` in `\pgfplotsset` (as well other `pgfplots` option settings).

Comment: The [scale only axis] option will produce consistent sized plots, albeit with variable bounding boxes.

Comment: I think i found a way to solve my problem although not an elegant one: x tick label style={xshift=-2.5mm}, and moves a bit the x labels to the left. This way it bounds the -5 tick label to the x axis limit and figures become the same size. Thanks for the help provided.